# How to remove Google search and smaller tile in Chrome 33's new tab page?

Tags: google-chrome

I updated Chrome to version 33.0.1750.117. Previously it was easy to remove the search and the tiles using the steps listed below, but now the option is not appearing.

1. Go to chrome://flags
2. Find:
   Enable Instant Extended API Mac, Windows, Chrome OS
   Enables the Instant Extended API which provides a deeper integration with your default search provider, including a renovated New Tab Page, extracting search query terms in the omnibox, a spruced-up omnibox dropdown and Instant previews of search results as you type in the omnibox.
3. Set it to 'Disabled'.

How can I remove it and get bigger tiles of most used URLs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an easy way to get half the way back - remove the annoying search field and google logo. I'm still bothered by the small thumbnails, but for now this is my suggestion:

The search bar and logo come from Google being defined as the default search provider. Change the search provider, and they go away. But what if you do want your searches to be done by Google?

Step 1: Create a file with the following text -

```
<html><head><script>
location.href = "https://www.google.com/search?" + location.href.split('?')[1];
</script><body></body></html>
```

Save it as `google_redirect.html` or so.

Step 2: Go to chrome://settings/searchEngines, scroll all the way down, and add the created HTML file as a new search engine. The URL should look like `file:///C:/<file_path>/google_redirect.html?q=%s`, where `<file_path>` should be replaced with the path of the folder in which the HTML file is stored.

Step 3: Set the new "search engine" as your default, and you're done.

After doing the above, Chrome will not recognize Google as your search provider, and will neither show the logo nor the search bar. Since the HTML page is local, the redirection of the query to Google should be instantaneous (online redirection pages will take much longer to be reached).

Step 4: Open a new tab and zoom in to make the thumbnails larger.

The New Tab Page change is really annoying. I expect extensions that restore previous behavior to appear soon, but at this moment I found no better solution.

Comment: I, personally, use [CoolNovo](http://coolnovo.com/), which is an extended version of Chrome that contains the older New Tab page. (no affiliation)

Comment: This solution has one disadvantage that, I can't get search suggestions in omnibox.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bibh/napglbchemndanaaaemlanobbneehgjb?hl=en-US) chrome extension. Very light weight. Disclaimer: I am the author of this extension.

Comment: Please refer to [this meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) post on how to recommend software in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to chrome folder and find the resources.pak file.
2. Open with notepad++(you might need administrator permission to change this            file).
3. Find 'var NUM_ROWS' in it. 
   You can use the find/search feature of notepad++.
4. set its value as : var NUM_ROWS=0;
5. save and close notepad++;
   congratulations!! you are done...now run chrome
   (you can tweak with with other variables there similarly)

Comment: This might be an answer but its unreadable with the formatting. Please edit and use formatting tools

Answer (score -1):

Use an earlier version of Chrome (Chromium 32.0.1690.0) there is no auto update and quick access page will be very comfortable